# Use c++ libraries at C#

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper

I'm working myself on a project, because performance is important i want to write some part of the code on c++ and want to call c++ codes from C#. I will write c++ library and want to write a C# wrapper, how can i do it? Have you any suggestion where i should begin to study? [any website, any link, any book]

Thanks !

Comment: Premature optimization is evil.  Do not do this until you know that C# is too slow.  (_hint_: It almost definitely isn't)

Comment: It seems unlikely that calling out to another library is really going to be that much faster, unless the code in that library runs repeatedly in a tight loop. As SLaks says, profile the code in C# first before wasting time writing it in C++ and P/Invoking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

Windows:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void SetWindowText(int h, String s);
```

Linux:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("/root/Desktop/q3noclient/libnoclient.so")]
static extern int DisconnectClient (string strServerIP, int iServerPort, string strClientIP, int iClientPort);
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("Comdlg32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern bool GetSaveFileName(ref OPENFILENAME lpofn);
```

VB.NET:

```
<DllImport("Comdlg32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetSaveFileName(ByRef lpofn As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either make C style imports for P/Invoke to use, like

```
void World_Hello(World* self) { self->Hello(); }
```

or investigate CallingConvention.ThisCall. Thanks to name mangling, if you want to be portable to other OSes the former is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at C++/CLI. I would recommend C++/CLI in Action by Nishant Sivakumar. Also, check this link out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163855.aspx#S7